# Meteor.js submit event

Tags: meteor

I was just playing around a bit with Meteor.js when I ran into this strange issue, I have a form with two textfields, but somehow my event is not listening to the submit.
When I remove one textfield, everything works fine ...

Below is my template for the form:

```
<template name="new_timer">
    <div class="timer timer--empty">
        <form id="new_timer">
            <input type="text" name="timer__name" class="timer__name" placeholder="Timer name">
            <input type="text" name="timer__description" class="timer__description" placeholder="Timer description">
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

And on the client side:

```
Template.new_timer.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        console.log('new timer');

        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

This doens't seem to work, however when I change my template to the following, it works

```
<template name="new_timer">
    <div class="timer timer--empty">
        <form id="new_timer">
            <input type="text" name="timer__name" class="timer__name" placeholder="Timer name">
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Am I just overlooking something very basic here?

Comment: How do you submit the form?

Comment: @PeppeL-G I was hoping the `submit` would just trigger when pressing enter. (Like how you normally submit it)

Comment: I'm not sure how it (should) works now days, but in the past you had to have a submit-button in the form in order for the "submit by pressing enter in a textfield" functionality to work.

Comment: Good point, if I add a submit butting it does work, guess I'll just hide it

Answer (score 1):

You might add an event like

```
'keyup form': function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Basically using a submit in a single page application is not adapted. In this kind of application everything is event based, you never reload a page so you never really 'submit' a form.

The 'form' tag becomes useless, most of developers (including me) are keeping it by habit but it is not required.

It is a bit late for an answer, I hope it can help somebody else!

Comment: The form element is not useless, for example it's great for posting the data (listen for the submit event, and not caring about if a send button has been pushed or if the enter key enter been hit in a text field), like in his problem.

Comment: If you listen to the submit event in a single page app, you are going to prevent the default process e.preventDefault()


So I do not think this event is really useful because we prevent its default behaviour.

Comment: In any case, your comment is right. It might be easier and probably more logic to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, submit event does not work with more inputs without this:

```
<input type="submit" hidden="hidden">
```